# make files to size zero if they have same checksum

Tags: perl

i have an array with path of all files(C files) in it.

I am using Perl

@array

```
C:\temp\a.c
C:\temp\b.c
C:\temp\x.c
C:\temp\y.c
C:\temp\z.c
```

few files although have different file name might have same checksum(which means they have same content). these exist only in pairs. i have to make size of one of them as 0.

CODE

```
use File::Checksum;

my %array;
foreach my $k(@files3)
{                       
      $array{$k} = Checksum($k, 100);   
}

# have to check if they have same checksum and make those file to size 0

#making file size to 0 is easy. 
#I just have to open file in write mode and then close it.
```

need help in how to compare checksum of all files in an array and get filename for those with same checksum

Comment: You can use the builtin `truncate`, but you shouldn't rely on just the checksum. You should make sure by comparing the actual contents of two files with the same checksum before truncating them.

Comment: I would check size of the filename and its checksum, if both match, they are the same, also make sure your checksum is good for large files, so I would rather use SHA512 rather than anything else... BTW: You can do what you want a lot easier using `sha512sum files` and use the output as a comparison for finding matches

Comment: As mentioned File::Checksum, uses a `checksum` algorithm, and is quite sensitive to similar files, I would use SHA512 rather than checksum for your task

Comment: Even then, still a good idea to check the files. Chances are you'll just have to read one block from each file.

Comment: thanks for your tips. will look into SHA512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a hash "array" is confusing. Naming it "hash" is less confusing, but something like "unique" or "checksum" might work even better.

Use the checksum as the key, not the filename:

```
my %checksum;
for my $f (@files) {
    push @{ $checksum{ Checksum($f, 100) } }, $f;
}
```

The hash of arrays now contains all the files grouped by checksum. Delete the duplicates:

```
for my $ch (keys %checksum) {
    my @same = @{ $checksum{$ch} };
    if (@same == 2) {
        open my $FH, '>', $same[1] or die $!;
    } elsif (@same > 2) {
        warn "More than 2 files: @same. None deleted.\n";
    }
}
```

(Untested.)